# How to read key codes of USB Keyboard with Media Keys

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Is it possible to read key codes of non-standard keys using an special iOS API or via the generic TextInput field? I have a multimedia keyboard with special buttons & like to make my iPad app aware of these key codes.

I know iOS can use some of them already (i.e. volume up/down, next/prev track).

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare to test. Good luck. I know there's an API somewhere that allows you to become the delegate of the keyboard and get keypresses character by character. I don't know how much data it gives you though, or what it's called.

Comment: Do you have an example of that Keyboard Keypress Delegate?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try subclassing UIApplication and overriding `sendEvent:` to see what events pass through there. Given that UIEvent doesn't document keyboard event support on iOS (as opposed to NSEvent in AppKit), I'm skeptical that you'll see keyboard events... but it's worth a try. I don't have a BT keyboard to try it out myself.

To use a UIApplication subclass, edit `main.m` and pass your subclass as the third argument to UIApplicationMain:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, YourApplicationSubclass, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

This strategy isn't uncommon in desktop Cocoa apps and is also explained here:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html